Hermite polynomial and the recurrence relation


\[
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty t^2 e^{-t^2} H_n^2(t) \, dt = \sqrt{\pi} \, 2^n n! \left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right).
\]

The problem states that this can be proven using the recurrence relation of Hermite polynomials.  
The recurrence relation is given by:
$$  
H_{n+1}(x) = 2xH_n(x) - 2nH_{n-1}(x).  
$$
Question:
How can I use the recurrence relation to derive the given integral property? Any step-by-step explanation or guidance would be helpful.

Tags:

orthogonal-polynomials
hermite-polynomials
recurrence-relations



Could you clarify what you have tried, and also what your notation means? Are the fancy square brackets just square brackets? If so, the integrand as written does not converge, as $e^{(-t)^2}=e^{t^2}$.

Previously posted and deleted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5007191/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5007165/42969. I suggest that you read why those questions were closed instead of just repeating an unclear, badly formatted no-context question.

Please use MathJax and show your attempt.

The question has been modified, please review it.

To solve for $H_n(t)$ using the recurrence relation:
$$H_{n+1}(t) = 2tH_n(t) - 2nH_{n-1}(t)$$
Rewriting it gives:
$$2tH_n(t) = H_{n+1}(t) + 2nH_{n-1}(t)$$
Divide all terms by $2$:
$$tH_n(t) = (1/2)H_{n+1}(t) + nH_{n-1}(t)$$
This provides a way to express $tH_n(t)$ in terms of $H_{n+1}(t)$ and $H_{n-1}(t)$.

Please use MathJax when formatting your answers. You can find a tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
